# Calling Class property using variables in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, variable-variables, class-properties

I am creating partials where an items property names are passed from an array to access the values of those properties but I receive an error saying `Undefined property of Namespace\Entity::$variable` when defining `$property->{$variable}`.  How would I go about getting this to work?

Here is an example of the code:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $thumb_sizes = [];
    foreach ($image_sizes as $thumb_size) {
        if(!empty($item->thumb{$thumb_size})) {
            array_push($thumb_sizes, preg_replace('/^http:/i','https:',$item->thumb{$thumb_size}));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accessing the property like this `$item->thumb{$thumb_size}`, it mean the `$item` has property `thumb` with array keys as the value. Here is the ilustration

```
class Item
{
    public $thumb = ["100x100" => "value", "75x75" => "value"];
}
```

But, if you imagine use this way `$item->thumb{$thumb_size}` to access property of `$item`, you cannot concatenate the property name with variable.
If you want to concatenate the variable, please do it first, and save to a variable. Then access the property using the variable name like this

```
$thumbSize = "thumb" . $thumb_size;
if(!empty($item->$thumbSize)) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```